# Python XML - count specific node below a node

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7, count, nodes

I need to get the number of all "**lvl**" nodes below "**to**" out of my XML. 
I use IronPython 2.7 and elementtree in Dynamo.
This is just an example XML, in truth it is much bigger.

There are two ways I try to get it, but it wouldn't work (I only show the first way below in my code).
**First**: "just" count the elements.
**Second**: insert the text value for every loop in a seperated list, so I can count the listelements after that.

Here is my XML:

```
<note>
    <note2>
        <yolo>
            <to>
                <type>
                    <game>
                        <name>Jani</name>
                        <lvl>111111</lvl>
                        <lvl>222222</lvl>
                        <fun>2222222</fun>
                    </game>
                    <game>
                        <name>Jani</name>
                        <lvl>111111</lvl>
                        <fun>2222222</fun>
                    </game>
                </type>
            </to>
            <to>
                <type>
                    <game>
                        <name>Bani</name>
                        <lvl>3333333</lvl>
                        <fun>44444444</fun>
                    </game>
                </type>
            </to>
        </yolo>
    </note2>
</note>
```

Here is my code:

```
import clr
import sys
clr.AddReference('ProtoGeometry')
from Autodesk.DesignScript.Geometry import *
sys.path.append("C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7\Lib")
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
xml="note.xml"
xpathstr=".//to//lvl"
tree = ET.parse(xml)
root = tree.getroot()
specific = root.findall(xpathstr)
list=[]
listcount=[]

for elem in specific:
    list.extend(elem.itertext())
    listcount.Add(len(elem))

print list,list2
```

So I try to count for every loop, but I get a list with only 0 values.
For my XML I expect a result like this: `Listcount[3,1]`.

Comment: Am I understand correctly that you want just count number of `lvl` belonging to  `yolo` tag?

Comment: I made a mistake,i need the counting for every lvl below the "to" tag separated. Sorry;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it!;), but its not perfect...I am open to other solutions...

here is my code:

```
import clr
import sys
clr.AddReference('ProtoGeometry')
from Autodesk.DesignScript.Geometry import *
sys.path.append("C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7\Lib")
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xml="note.xml"
xpathstr =".//to//lvl"
xpathstr2 =".//to"
searchforxpath= ".//lvl"

tree = ET.parse(xml)
list=[]
listcount=[]

root = tree.getroot()
specific = root.findall(xpathstr)
countmatch = root.findall(xpathstr2)

for elem in countmatch:
    listcount.append(elem.iterfind(searchforxpath))

for elem in specific:
    list.append(elem.text)


print list, listcount
```

I added **two new xpath**, so i can search for "**lvl**" within "**to**".
After this i count all objects in listcount.